# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}-\{2\}\to\mathbb{R}-\{5\}$ with $f(x)=\frac{5x-1}{x-2}$ is bijective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can anyone please help to explain the question and what actually $f: \mathbb{R} - \{2\}$  means ??
I know that bijection means  one to one function and onto both. Any idea to start up with this question?  Thanks

prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}- \{2\} \to \mathbb{R} - \{5\}$ defined by $f(x) = (5x+1)/(x-2)$  is a bijection . (where $\mathbb{R}$ is a real number sign)

how can i first prove that is one to one ?

Answer (score 3):

In this context, $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$ means the set of all real numbers that are different from $x$.

**Injective**: if $f(s)=f(t)$ then $\frac{5s+1}{s-2}=\frac{5t+1}{t-2}$ so that
$$
(5s+1)(t-2)=(5t+1)(s-2)\implies 5st-10s+t-2=5st-10t+s-2
$$
which simplifies to imply that $s=t$.

**Surjective**: suppose that $y$ is any number in $\mathbb{R}-\{5\}$, let us demonstrate that there is $x$ not equal $2$ such that $f(x)=y$:
$$
y=f(x)=\frac{5x+1}{x-2}=\frac{5x-10}{x-2}+\frac{11}{x-2}\iff y=5+\frac{11}{x-2}
$$
which gives
$$
x-2=\frac{11}{y-5}\iff x=2+\frac{11}{y-5}.
$$
The fraction $\frac{11}{y-5}$ is well-defined ($y\neq 5$) and nonzero, so $x$ is indeed distinct from $2$.

Comment: Saying that, Did you mean set of all real numbers except set 2 / {2}  ?? Could you please tell me what exact value of s and t can be ? because if s = 2 and t = 3 in the above equation i can't get S = T .

Comment: In symbols, $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}=\{r\in\mathbb{R}:r\neq x\}$. To prove that $f$ is injective (i.e. one-to-one), you just need to demonstrate that if $s,t\in\mathbb{R}-\{2\}$ are such that $f(t)=f(s)$, then it must be that $t=s$. Note that your example of $s=2$ is not valid.

Comment: I tried placing s = 3 and t = 4 in the above equation but ended up getting non equal values 39 and 41. so, I am a bit confused whether the function is one to one or not.

Comment: That's to be expected: if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(s)\neq f(t)$ if $s\neq t$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also show an explicit inverse, $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R} -\lbrace 5 \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R} -\lbrace 2 \rbrace$, where $f^{-1}(x)= \frac{2x+1}{x-5}$ and use that

$$f\ \  \text{is one-to-one if, and only if, has a left inverse}$$
That is, $f^{-1} \circ f(x) = f^{-1}(f(x))=x \in \mathbb{R} - \lbrace 2 \rbrace$

$$f\ \ \text{ is onto if, and only if, has a right inverse}$$

That is, $f \circ f^{-1}(x)= f(f^{-1}(x)) = x \in \mathbb{R} -\lbrace 5 \rbrace $.

Comment: i understood the injective explanation. But , didn't get the way done for surjective above. Could anyone explain please? thanks

Comment: Try to show that, $f(f^{-1}(x)) = \frac{5(\frac{2x+1}{x-5})-1}{(\frac{2x+1}{x-5}) - 2} = x$. This shows that f has a right inverse, which is the same as being surjective.

Comment: when i solve it I got x = 5 . So , does that mean it's not onto ??

Comment: It means something went wrong, because $\frac{5(\frac{2x+1}{x-5}) + 1}{(\frac{2x+1}{x-5}) - 2} = \frac{(10x+5) + x - 5}{(2x + 1) - 2x + 10} = \frac{11x}{11} = x$.