# Proving onto and 1-1 functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I understand the 1-1 function side of things, but I still don't really get how to prove that the function is onto

Question:
Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}-\{2\} \to \mathbb{R}-\{5\}$ defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{5x+1}{x-2}$ is a bijection.

So far for 1-1:

Assume that $f(a)=f(b)$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}-\{2\}$. Then $\dfrac{5a+1}{a-2}=\dfrac{5b+1}{b-2}$.

Cross-multiplying both sides by $(a-2)(b-2)$, we obtain $(5a+1)(b-2)=(5b+1)(a-2)$.

Simplifying, we have $5ab-10a+b-2=5ab-10b+a-2$.

Adding $-5ab$ to both sides and dividing by $-10$, we obtain $b-2=a-2$.

Adding $-2$ on both sides, we obtain $b=a$.

$\therefore f(x)=(5x+1)/(x-2)$ is 1-1.

But I'm not sure how to prove that it is onto. Can anyone help (and explain) how to prove that it is onto, so it is easy to understand?

Thanks.

Comment: What is range$f$? Does range$f = \mathbb{R} - \{5\}$?

Comment: Unfortunately, our lecturer does go over the questions, but we don't have a lot of examples to do them and also, we don't spend too much time on them

Comment: Have a look at its [graph][1] and see whether horizontal lines, $y=b$, where $b$ is a constant different from $5$, meet it. Then rigorously solve equation $b= (5x+1)/(x-2)$ (look for $x$, different from $2$, in terms of $b$).




[1]:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D+%285x%2B1%29%2F%28x-2%29

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938289/show-that-f-mathbbr-2-to-mathbbr-5-with-fx-frac5x-1x-2-i/938328#938328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show onto, you must prove that every element in your range gets used. To do this, pick $y \in \Bbb{R}-\{5\}$. We must now prove that we can always find some $x \in \Bbb{R}-\{2\}$ such that $f(x)=y$. This would mean $$\frac{5x+1}{x-2}=y \\ \implies 5x+1 = yx-2y \\ \implies 5x-yx = -2y-1 \\ \implies x(5-y) = -(2y+1) \\ \implies x = -\frac{2y+1}{5-y} \\ \implies x = \frac{2y+1}{y-5}$$ We never have to worry about dividing by zero, because $y \neq 5$. So given $y \in \Bbb{R}-\{5 \}$ we know we can find $x=\frac{2y+1}{y-5} \in \Bbb{R}-\{2 \}$. This satisfies the condition of onto.

Comment: Thanks, for that

So basically \mathbb{R}-\{5\}$ is where y can not equal 5?

Comment: That was the assumption right? The range of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}-\{5\}$ which means every real number except $5$. That means we can pick any number we want out of that range and never have to worry about choosing $5$. This is great, because the definition of $x$ I gave in terms of $y$, $x = \frac{2y+1}{y-5}$ is invalid precisely when $y=5$. Again, that can never happen, so our equation for $x$ is always valid.

Comment: Oh, I see what that means

Thanks, very much

Comment: Hey, @graydad

Quick question, how did that negative fraction become positive, because, looks like that $5-y$ is turned round to $y-5$

Comment: Oh, wait,

Basically, we had to make it $-5$, because of $y\in\mathbb{R}-{{5}}$ ?

Comment: Not quite: the set $\Bbb{R}-\{5\}$ has nothing to do with $-5$. It means that $5$ is removed from the set of real numbers, so you have everything BUT $5$. If you wanted to have the set of real numbers NOT including $-5$ then you would write $\Bbb{R}-\{-5\}$. As for the weird algebra move I did, this is what happened. I assume you follow my algebra up to this point? $$x=-\frac{2y+1}{5-y}$$ If so, then here is what I did: $$x=-\frac{2y+1}{5-y} \\ = \frac{-1(2y+1)}{5-y} \\ = \frac{-1(2y+1)}{-1(y-5)} \\ = \frac{-1}{-1}\cdot \frac{2y+1}{y-5} \\ = 1\cdot \frac{2y+1}{y-5} \\ = \frac{2y+1}{y-5} $$

Comment: Oh, I see

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{5\}$.  We need to find $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{2\}$ so that $f(a)=b$

We need $\frac{5a+1}{a-2}=b$

$ab-2b=5a+1$

$a=\frac{2b+1}{b-5}$

You still need to confirm that $a\ne 2$.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is onto or surjective if range $f = Y$, ie. for every $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use LaTex to write maths.

Anyway, $f:X\to Y$ is said 'onto' if $Y=f(X)$, that is

$$\forall y \in Y, \exists x\in X : y=f(x)$$

That is, for every number in the codomain you can find a number in the domain which is mapped by $f$ to the first one.

Let $y$ be a real number $\not =5$. You have to find $x$ such that
$$\frac{5x+1}{x-2}=y$$

Linearize and you get $5x+1=y(x-2)$ and now solve for $x$.

$$x=\frac{-2y-1}{5-y}$$.

Since $y\not =5$, you found the number  $x$ which is mapped to $y$ for every $y$ in the codomain.

Comment: Thanks,
Yea, I'm new to this, but thanks for the tip

So, basically, for this one, we just want to make x the subject?

Comment: Surjectivity means "the image covers the whole codomain" so you just have to prove that you can actually do that covering. That is, show how to do it, so find the x's that work good.